# Setting Vista to send only some traffic through VPN

Tags: windows-vista, vpn, bittorrent, utorrent

I use uTorrent to download files, and would like to do so with some level of encryption. I have signed up to http://itshidden.com to use their VPN service, and have connected to it using the Network and Sharing center. 
However when i connect to the VPN all my network traffic, web browsing and uTorrent, is routed through the VPN. Is is possible to set it up so that the uTorrent traffic is sent through the VPN, but all other traffic such as web browsing is not?

Answer (score 3):

It could be done with static routing - by connecting to the VPN, it'll be changing your default gateway, but you could still route other traffic via a different gateway.

To add a new route your use the command:

```
 route ADD 157.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0  157.55.80.1 METRIC 3
        destination^      ^mask      ^gateway     metric^
```

Lower metric values get used over higher ones, so if your VPN gateway had a lower metric, you'd have to use route change.

You'd need to add either routes for all destinations you didn't want to reach via the VPN, or vice-versa.

Comment: I second this, i use Cisco vpn which does the same thing, it automatically adds routes for certain set of ip's so that they go on vpn while others go through regular route.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about VPN, that would not be possible.  The idea of a Virtual Private Network is to create a tunnel from endpoint to endpoint such that your computer is logically on the far end network rather than on the near network.  If you have two network interfaces, you could possibly connect them both to your home network and only attach one to the VPN, but then I'm not sure how to configure Vista to send some traffic through one and some through the other...

Have you looked at enabling transport encryption in uTorrent?  I use Vuze, but I'm sure you can do the same thing in uTorrent.  I have mine set to use transport encryption and only accept connections from other using encryption as well.